# Dash - modifying variables entered through app layout to pass on to callbacks

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

Most of the dash examples that I see have the same variable entered through the layout and then passed onto the callback as input or state.  If I want to pass a modified variable (e.g. select a dict value with the app layout input being the key) to the call back, how would I do it without a chained callback ?

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far, even if it is not yet working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It is through the 'label' and 'value' in options in dropdown.  The 'Label' is what the user sees, while the 'value' is what is passed through the callback